# How to deal with lost client connections in Apache Qpid + MRg

Tags: qpid

Using the c++ client, it seems that if for some reason the connection  is lost to the server, for example through power failure, manual termination, network , then the server does not detect that the client is lost. An open connection (or half open) is kept. How can this be prevented? Is there some server side heartbeat option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client connection to the broker has a connection option called heartbeat. Heartbeat option values are a integer representing time in seconds. Heartbeats keepalive frames are sent every N seconds. If two successive heartbeats are missed the connection is considered to be lost.

See [connection options](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.26/programming/book/connection-options.html)